# Calculate the dollar amount in a particular column within excel to output another value

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to find out what formula will select the dollar amount in Column A so that it will output a particular set of numbers based on that dollar amount.

Example:

```
Column A                         Column B
benefactor sponsor $1,250        1
benefactor sponsor $10,000       8
benefactor sponsor $6,250        6
```

The formula should look at column A and based on the dollar within the description of each cell determine what number to assign it to be provided in column B.

Comment: Um, what is your logic for applying the number in Column B?

Comment: For the dollar amount that is $1250 they would get a 1 in column B

Comment: for the dollar amount of $6,250 they would get 6.  For dollar amount of $10,000 they would get 8.

Comment: Those are the only 3?

Comment: No there are multiple others but if I can get some guidance how to do these three I can possibly add more to the formula to accommodate the rest.

Comment: can you strip the text out, or do you have to have the "benefactor sponsor " in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having text in the string adds another level of complexity, but ultimately this is an `INDEX(MATCH(`... problem.

You'll need to create a small reference table that has the dollar amounts and values you want in your column B.

The formula will look something like this:

```
=INDEX($F$3:$F$5,MATCH(VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("$",A1),10)),$E$3:$E$5,1))
```

[image]

`SEARCH` finds the starting position of the dollar amount.

`MID` parses out the dollar amount portion of the string.

`VALUE` converts that portion to a numeric